# Why does Python unittest auto-discovery not work when running in a subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-unittest, autodiscovery

I'd like to be able to run Python's `unittest` module programmatically via a subprocess (e.g. `subprocess.Popen()`, `subprocess.run()`, `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec()`) and have it auto-discover tests.

I do not want to run the tests by importing the `unittest` module into my script, because I would like the same code to be able to run *any* arbitrary command from the command line, and I'd like to avoid handling running tests differently than other commands.

### Example Code

Here is a GitHub repository with code that illustrates the issue I'm seeing: https://github.com/sscovil/python-subprocess

For completeness, I'll include it here as well.

```
.
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── example
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── runner.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── example
        ├── __init__.py
        └── runner_test.py
```

**src/example/runner.py**

```py
import asyncio
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import unittest
from subprocess import CompletedProcess, PIPE
from typing import Final, List

UNIT_TEST_CMD: Final[str] = "python -m unittest discover test '*_test.py' --locals -b -c -f"


def _parse_cmd(cmd: str) -> List[str]:
    """Helper function that splits a command string into a list of arguments with a full path to the executable."""
    args: List[str] = cmd.split(" ")
    args[0] = shutil.which(args[0])
    return args


async def async_exec(cmd: str, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Runs a command using asyncio.create_subprocess_exec() and logs the output."""
    cmd_args: List[str] = _parse_cmd(cmd)
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, *args, **kwargs)
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
    if stdout:
        print(stdout.decode().strip())
    else:
        print(stderr.decode().strip())
    return process.returncode


def popen(cmd: str, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Runs a command using subprocess.call() and logs the output."""
    cmd_args: List[str] = _parse_cmd(cmd)
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, text=True, *args, **kwargs) as process:
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
        if stdout:
            print(stdout.strip())
        else:
            print(stderr.strip())
        return process.returncode


def run(cmd: str, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Runs a command using subprocess.run() and logs the output."""
    cmd_args: List[str] = _parse_cmd(cmd)
    process: CompletedProcess = subprocess.run(cmd_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, check=True, *args, **kwargs)
    if process.stdout:
        print(process.stdout.decode().strip())
    else:
        print(process.stderr.decode().strip())
    return process.returncode


def unittest_discover() -> unittest.TestResult:
    """Runs all tests in the given directory that match the given pattern, and returns a TestResult object."""
    start_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "test")
    pattern = "*_test.py"
    tests = unittest.TextTestRunner(buffer=True, failfast=True, tb_locals=True, verbosity=2)
    results = tests.run(unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover(start_dir=start_dir, pattern=pattern))
    return results


def main():
    """Runs the example."""
    print("\nRunning tests using asyncio.create_subprocess_exec...\n")
    asyncio.run(async_exec(UNIT_TEST_CMD))

    print("\nRunning tests using subprocess.Popen...\n")
    popen(UNIT_TEST_CMD)

    print("\nRunning tests using subprocess.run...\n")
    run(UNIT_TEST_CMD)

    print("\nRunning tests using unittest.defaultTestLoader...\n")
    unittest_discover()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**test/example/runner_test.py**

```py
import unittest

from src.example.runner import async_exec, popen, run, unittest_discover


class AsyncTestRunner(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_async_call(self):
        self.assertEqual(await async_exec("echo Hello"), 0)


class TestRunners(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_popen(self):
        self.assertEqual(popen("echo Hello"), 0)

    def test_run(self):
        self.assertEqual(run("echo Hello"), 0)

    def test_unittest_discover(self):
        results = unittest_discover()
        self.assertEqual(results.testsRun, 4)  # There are 4 test cases in this file


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

### Expected Behavior

When running tests from the command line, Python's `unittest` module auto-discovers tests in the `test` directory:

```bash
python -m unittest discover test '*_test.py' --locals -bcf
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.855s

OK
```

### Actual Behavior

...but it fails to auto-discover tests when that same command is run using Python's `subprocess` module:

```bash
$ python -m src.example.runner

Running tests using asyncio.create_subprocess_exec...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

Running tests using subprocess.Popen...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

Running tests using subprocess.run...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

Running tests using unittest.defaultTestLoader...

test_async_call (example.runner_test.AsyncTestRunner.test_async_call) ... ok
test_popen (example.runner_test.TestRunners.test_popen) ... ok
test_run (example.runner_test.TestRunners.test_run) ... ok
test_unittest_discover (example.runner_test.TestRunners.test_unittest_discover) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.864s

OK
```

Note that the `unittest.defaultTestLoader` test runner works as expected, because it is explicitly using the `unittest` module to run the other tests. However, when running tests using `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec`, `subprocess.Popen`, or `subprocess.run`, as if using the CLI from the command line, the tests are not auto-discovered.

### Different Python Versions

If you have Docker installed, you can run the tests in a container using any version of Python you like.  For example:

#### Python 3.11 on Alpine Linux

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):$(pwd) -w $(pwd) --name test python:3.11-alpine python3 -m src.example.runner
```

#### Python 3.10 on Ubuntu Linux

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):$(pwd) -w $(pwd) --name test python:3.10 python3 -m src.example.runner
```

In every version I tried, from 3.8 to 3.11, I saw the same results.

### Question

Why does Python `unittest` auto-discovery not work when running in a subprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with running in a subprocess. Your `cmd_args` is broken.

You wrote a command line like what you'd write in a shell, but it doesn't go through any of the processing a shell would apply. It goes through your own custom processing, where you split it on single spaces and then try to locate the executable with `shutil.which`.

One of the processing steps the shell would apply is quote removal, which is what would remove the `'` characters from your `'*_test.py'` pattern if you ran that command in a shell. Because this isn't going through a shell, those characters remain in the argument, so you end up telling unittest test discovery to look for test files with `'` characters at the start and end of their names.

You don't have any test files with `'` characters at the start and end of their names, and such names would be incompatible with test discovery even if you had any, so test discovery finds nothing.

---

You need to do something that results in a valid argv list, without quotation marks in the pattern. I recommend just writing out the list manually:

```
cmd = [
    'python',
    '-m',
    'unittest',
    'discover',
    'test',
    '*_test.py',
    '--locals',
    '-b',
    '-c',
    '-f',
]
```

Alternatively, you could keep your current command line processing and just remove the `'` characters from your `UNIT_TEST_CMD`, but with how shell-like your command looks, it's too easy to get mixed up about the syntax you're using.

It's also possible to just invoke a shell to process your command line with `asyncio.create_subprocess_shell`, or using `shell=True` with `subprocess`, but it's way too easy to create subtle security holes when relying on shell processing.

Comment: ‍♂️ wow. Thank you. That was driving me insane. I only added that command parser bit because of the warning I saw in the Popen docs — https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen — that says, "For maximum reliability, use a fully qualified path for the executable. To search for an unqualified name on PATH, use shutil.which()."

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is correct, it should be noted that the root cause of the problem I was having can be resolved using [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) instead of [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), as I had originally done.

**src/example/runner.py**

```py
import asyncio
import os
import shlex
import shutil
import subprocess
import unittest
from subprocess import CompletedProcess, PIPE
from typing import Final, List

UNIT_TEST_CMD: Final[str] = "python -m unittest discover test '*_test.py' --locals -b -c -f"


def _parse_cmd(cmd: str) -> List[str]:
    """Helper function that splits a command string into a list of arguments with a full path to the executable."""
    args: List[str] = shlex.split(cmd)
    args[0] = shutil.which(args[0])
    return args
```

From the docs:

> shlex.split(s, comments=False, posix=True)
>
> Split the string s using shell-like syntax. If comments is False (the default), the parsing of comments in the given string will be disabled (setting the commenters attribute of the shlex instance to the empty string). This function operates in POSIX mode by default, but uses non-POSIX mode if the posix argument is false.

This method correctly parses the given command, even when some arguments are wrapped in quotes. It also avoids issues that can be caused when the text wrapped in quotes contains spaces. For example:

```py
cmd = "python3 -c \"import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())\""
```

Using `str.split()`, this would result in:

```bash
  File "<string>", line 1
    "import
    ^
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1)
Error: Command '['/Users/username/project/venv/bin/python3', '-c', '"import', 'uuid;', 'print(uuid.uuid4())"']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

However, using `shlex.split()`, it works correctly:

```bash
ad7ecf00-83c3-4593-b1ef-262e5adf7594
```